# Testing CanCanCan ability definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rolify, cancancan

I'm using CanCanCan with Rolify and I´m trying to test my Ability class authorization.

When testing if a unprivileged user can `CRUD` other users in the system the test fails

```
1) Ability a guest user should not be able to manage others
 Failure/Error: expect(subject).to_not be_able_to(:crud, User)
   expected not to be able to :crud User(...)
```

But I can't find any reason why the check in my Ability class fails:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user = User.new)
    alias_action :create, :read, :update, :destroy, :destroy_multiple, to: :crud

    # What is wrong?
    can :crud, User, id: user.id

    if user.has_role?(:admin)
      can :manage, User
    end
  end
end
```

This is my spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'cancan/matchers'

RSpec.describe Ability do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  subject { Ability.new(user) }

  context "a guest user" do
    it "should be able to manage self" do
      expect(subject).to be_able_to(:crud, user)
    end

    it "should not be able to manage others" do
      expect(subject).to_not be_able_to(:crud, User)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: rails (4.1.6), rolify (3.4.1), cancancan (1.9.2)

Comment: `expect(subject).to_not be_able_to(:crud, User)` why you are referencing model User, not instance there?

Comment: Changed it to `expect(subject).to_not be_able_to(:crud, User.new)` and the test passed, thanks @FelixBorzik

Comment: @FelixBorzik feel free to add it as an answer if you want rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
expect(subject).to_not be_able_to(:crud, User)
```

You are referencing User model, not instance there. Use User.new or another persisted User instance.